Whenever I try to reverse the order of the time slots, I am unable to select even they are consecutive
I'm working on a web application where users are required to select a minimum of two time slots for booking appointments. Additionally, these selected time slots must be consecutive, meaning that there should be no gaps between them. Despite implementing JavaScript validation to enforce this requirement, the system still identifies selected time slots as non-consecutive, even when they are. Any insights on why this validation isn't working as expected would be greatly appreciated.
enter image description here
enter image description here
This is my html code with the JavaScript function:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time Slot Selection</title>
    <style>
        .available {
            color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
        }
        .not-available {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function validateSlots() {
            // Get the selected checkboxes
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
            var selectedSlots = Array.from(checkboxes).map(checkbox => parseInt(checkbox.value));
            
            console.log("Selected Slots:", selectedSlots); // Log selected slots

            // Check if at least 2 slots are selected
            if (selectedSlots.length < 2) {
                alert("Please select at least 2 slots.");
                return false;
            }

            // Sort the selected slots in descending order
            selectedSlots.sort((a, b) => b - a);

            // Check if the selected slots are consecutive
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedSlots.length - 1; i++) {
                // Calculate the difference between consecutive slots
                var difference = selectedSlots[i] - selectedSlots[i + 1];

                // Log the index of the selected slot
                console.log("Index:", i);

                // Log the difference between consecutive slots
                console.log("Difference:", difference);

                // If the difference is not 1, slots are not consecutive
                if (difference !== 1) {
                    alert("Selected slots must be consecutive.");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // If all checks pass, allow form submission
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a Time Slot for {{ selected_date }}</h1>
    {% if error_message %}
        <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'sbapp:confirm_slots' %}" onsubmit="return validateSlots()">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            {% for slot in time_slots reversed %}
                <li>
                    <!-- Wrap the entire time slot display in a span -->
                    <span {% if slot.slot.status == 'not_available' %} class="not-available" {% endif %}>
                        <!-- Display the time slot -->
                        {{ slot.slot.start_time }} - {{ slot.slot.end_time }}
                        
                        <!-- Display the checkbox if slot is available -->
                        {% if slot.slot.status == 'available' %}
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selected_slots" value="{{ slot.serial_number }}">
                        {% endif %}
                    </span>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_date" value="{{ selected_date }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Selection">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Whenever I select 2 consecutive slots; I want them to get booked. That's it here.

First, you will need to sort the selected timeslots and then just compare the EndTime of the first time slot with the StartTime of the next selected time slot.
E.g.
If the user has selected two-time slots as below:Timeslot1: [StartTime1-EndTime1]Timeslot2: [StartTime2-EndTime2]
Step 1: Sort the selected timeslots first
Step 2: (Assuming the above time slots are sorted) Compare whether
EndTime1=StartTime2.


function areTimeslotsConsecutive(timeslots) {
    // Convert timeslots to Date objects for comparison
    timeslots = timeslots.map(slot => ({
        start: new Date(`1970-01-01T${slot.start}:00`),
        end: new Date(`1970-01-01T${slot.end}:00`)
    }));

    // Sort timeslots by start time
    timeslots.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);

    // Check for consecutive timeslots
    for (let i = 0; i < timeslots.length - 1; i++) {
        if (timeslots[i].end.getTime() !== timeslots[i + 1].start.getTime()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Example usage
let timeslots1 = [
    { start: "09:00", end: "10:00" },
    { start: "10:00", end: "11:00" }
];
console.log(areTimeslotsConsecutive(timeslots1));  // Output: true



